# How can I send a message from a standard library spawned thread to a Tokio async task?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

I have a setup where my program spawns several threads for CPU-bound computation using the `std::thread::spawn`.

I need a GRPC server to handle incoming commands and also stream outputs done by the worker threads. I'm using `tonic` for the GRPC server, and it only offers an async implementation inside a Tokio future.

I need to be able to send messages from my "normal" standard-library threads to the Tokio future.

I've boiled my code down the the minimum here:

```
use std::thread;
use tokio::sync::mpsc; // 1.9.0

fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

    let tokio_runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tokio_runtime.spawn(async move {
        // the code below starts the GRPC server in reality, here I'm just demonstrating trying to receive a message
        while let Some(v) = rx.recv().await {}
    });

    let h = thread::spawn(move || {
        // do work
        tx.send(1).await; //<------ error occurs here since I can't await in a non-async block
    });

    h.join().unwrap();
}
```

How can my main worker threads communicate with the Tokio-spawned GRPC server?

Comment: Use an unbounded channel, so that the non-async thread does not need to wait.

Comment: `mpsc::channel(1)` here is a tokio channel, I see the function must take a buffer > 0

Comment: I need the `tokio::sync::mpsc` channel because inside the tokio runtime, I need the `recv().await` so it doesn't block

Comment: https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.unbounded_channel.html `UnboundedSender.send` is not async and does not block.

Comment: using unbounded queues is generally a very bad idea as it can lead to OOM and other kinds of resource exhaustion.  Using a bounded channel with [blocking_send()](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.blocking_send) is better

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tokio's `sync` features. There are two options - [`UnboundedSender`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.UnboundedSender.html) and [`Sender::blocking_send()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.blocking_send).

The issue with the unbounded sender is that it does not have back-pressure and if your producer is faster than the consumer your application may crash with an out-of-memory error or exhaust other limited resources your producer uses.

As a general rule, you should avoid using unbounded queues, which leaves us with the better option of using `blocking_send()`:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de88ae2d5b8ff9ed58ca21e7bad48046):

```rust
use std::thread;
use tokio::sync::mpsc; // 1.9.0

fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);

    let tokio_runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tokio_runtime.spawn(async move {
        // the code below starts the GRPC server in reality, here I'm just demonstrating trying to receive a message
        while let Some(v) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("Received: {:?}", v);
        }
    });

    let h = thread::spawn(move || {
        // do work
        tx.blocking_send(1).unwrap();
    });

    h.join().unwrap();
}
```